# dplyr distinct over two columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a table where the first two rows are sample identifiers and the third a measure of distance eg:

```
df<-data.table(H1=c(1,2,3,4,5),H2=c(7,3,2,8,9), D=c(100,4,55,66,35))
```

I want to find only the unique pairs across both columns, ie 1-7,2-3,4-8,5-9.  Removing the duplicate 2-3 and 3-2 pairings which appears in different columns but keeping the third row (which being a distance is identical for 2-3 and 3-2).

Comment: What is the logic behind keeping the 3rd row and not the 2nd?

Comment: I'll post a solution that will hopefully help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# example data
df<-data.frame(H1=c(1,2,3,4,5),
               H2=c(7,3,2,8,9), 
               D=c(100,4,55,66,35), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%             # for each row
  mutate(HH = paste0(sort(c(H1,H2)), collapse = ",")) %>% # create a new variable that orders and combines H1 and H2
  group_by(HH) %>%          # group by that variable
  filter(D == max(D)) %>%   # keep the row where D is the maximum (assumed logic*)
  ungroup() %>%             # forget the grouping
  select(-HH)               # remove unnecessary variable

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#      H1    H2     D
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     7   100
# 2     3     2    55
# 3     4     8    66
# 4     5     9    35
```

*Note: No idea what your logic is to keep 1 row from the duplicates. I had to use something as an example and here I'm keeping the row with the highest `D` value. This logic can change if needed.

Comment: I think the OP rather wants `distinct(HH, .keep_all = TRUE)`. Oops just only now understood the problem of the ties sorry

Comment: Oops I meant column not row, anyway I can adapt the above which is a nice structure to use, thanks.